# Limit sending emails via php

Tags: linux, php, email, debian, php.ini

Is there any way to limit amount of emails user can send per day ? I run different php.ini for every user so ideal would be to limit this in .ini file

ty.

Comment: It would help you let us know which MTA you are using.

Comment: Hello. I am using Exim

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something better managed via exim than PHP.  [this thread](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16101) explains how